# Como posso mudar o servidor de DNS de um dispositivo via aplicação?

Tags: java, android, dns

Estou a fazer uma aplicação para mudar o servidor de DNS, tanto em WiFi como em rede móvel, para android mas ainda não consegui descobrir a forma de o fazer. Já pesquisei em vários locais, incluindo na documentação, mas não sei como o fazer.

Alguém me pode dizer a "direção" para onde ir?

Comment: Se não me engano, não tem como, sem acesso root. Só criando uma VPN privada no aparelho e nela, configurando isso.

Comment: @Articuno E sabes como posso fazer isso? Obrigado já agora.

Comment: Não sei bem como te ajudar pois nunca programei isso pra android.